# Snyk How to set reviewers on automatic pull requests (Bitbucket Cloud)

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud, snyk

I'm using Snyk Bitbucket Cloud integration. Is there a way to add a group of reviewers on automatic pull requests (Bitbucket Cloud). At this moment, the pull requests are created without reviewers. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible to do today using the stock integration, but if you're willing to do some custom integration work you can use the [BitBucket APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v808/intro/) to make this happen.

Source: I work at Snyk and spoke to our internal team to verify this information.